# Serverpod Webserver URL

Tags: serverpod

Question regarding the Webserver (I know in beta)

Situation: I want to access a static asset (e.g. an image) on the webserver static part from within flutter. Quite a common scenario i guess.

Problem: How do I construct the URL?
More precise: how do I get the host URL (different in development, staging, production)

I know the server holds the info in the `/config/{env}.yaml`
But how do those info travel through the `serverpod_client`(?) into flutter?

Was not able to find anything in the docs.
There is the [`serverpod_client.host`](https://pub.dev/documentation/serverpod_client/latest/serverpod_client/ServerpodClientShared/host.html) property but that points (obviously) to the "api" host NOT the webserver, and they might be very differnt.
e.g. `api.myapp.com` vs `www.myapp.com`

Answer (score 0):

Currently not handled automatically, you will have to set this up yourself.

This can easily be done by using [flavors](https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/flavors) of the app.

Where you setup one flavor for production, one for staging, etc.